# ng-change is wiping out the pre-selected drop down option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been implementing some live searching using ng-change and it is working very well apart from this issue I have with a pre-selected drop down box.

When I serve up the page, I set the **selected="selected"** I want to be the default option. However, when the page loads, it just jumps to the top option. I need the drop down box to stay on option three.

```
<html>
<body >

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http)
       {
       });
</script>

<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./Test2.aspx" id="aspnetForm">

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select name="DropDownTest" id="DropDownTest" ng-model="LiveSearchOptions" ng-change="SearchFieldChanged()">
      <option value="">ALL</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</form>
```

When I remove the module (by just deleting the script tags) it works ok. Can you advise please? I am quite new to this!

JS Fiddle to play about with
https://jsfiddle.net/4to3ux4g/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attached an `ng-model` to the controller. So the `selected` attribute is getting overridden by value in your `ng-model`

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http)
  {
     $scope.LiveSearchOptions = '3';
  });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/bbsymmr8/1/